# KDE's network applet not listing APs, while iwlist does after some extra steps

Tags: networking, wifi, kde, networkmanager

KDE's network applet doesn't list any wireless network.  It used to, but I must have made an unintended change.  This much I know about my situation (the device is called `wlp4s0`):

Upon login, the applet has two initially unticked and unlabelled tick boxes, one of which must be the "enable wireless" one.

On the command line, my only route to listing present networks with `iwlist wlp4s0 scan` requires these steps:

```
rfkill unblock all
sudo ifconfig wlp4s0 up
```

To get to a network listing, these steps are necessary each time after login or switching the device off and on, and the device is always down upon login.

My OS is:

```
Linux miraculix 4.2.0-34-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 10 22:13:01 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

KDE:

```
$ plasmashell -v
plasmashell 5.4.2
```

I have also deleted and re-created my kwallet settings to rule out that kind of permission issue.

Any help to get my KDE network applet to recognize networks again is appreciated.